# Getting selected date from calender in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi want to show task created on particular date by just selecting the date from the full month calendar.

[image]

there are several task created on this date. so for this I want to fire a jquery event which will fetch data against that date and will return.

but my problem is that I need selected date so that I can pass it in my node js function.

any help how can I get selected date .

I am using this calendar

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pages/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
<script src="pages/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="box box-primary">
  <div class="box-body no-padding">
    <!-- THE CALENDAR -->
    <div id="calendar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQueryUI Datepicker has an option `onSelect` that you can pass as a property to the `options` object that you can pass to the `.datepicker` function.

```
$('#calendar').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date, datepicker) {
        // date is the selected date as a string
        // datepicker is the instance of the calendar itself
    }
});
```

In there you can fetch the data you need from your Node.js service and use it to visualize the tasks that are planned for that date.

Documentation for the jQueryUI Datepicker widget:
https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker

Reading the documentation you might even find a way to make multi-date selection a thing!
I hope this helped you.

Comment: I wrote this code but this event if not fired. not working

Comment: Please update your post with the code you've written. I tested it in CodePen and it works exactly as it's supposed to. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wEJXRW

Comment: thanks it is working. problem was js file clash with other js file